# Delete duplicates using dense rank

Tags: sql, hive

I have a sales data table with `cust_id`s and their transaction dates.
I want to create a table that stores, for every customer, their `cust_id`, their last purchased date (on the basis of transaction dates) and the count of times they have purchased.

I wrote this code:

```
SELECT
    cust_xref_id, txn_ts,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_xref_id ORDER BY CAST(txn_ts as timestamp) DESC) AS rank,
    COUNT(txn_ts)
FROM
    sales_data_table
```

But I understand that the above code would give an output like this (attached example picture)

[image]

How do I modify the code to get an output like :

[image]

I am a beginner in SQL queries and would really appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be an aggregation query which changes the table key from `(customer_id, date)` to `(customer_id)`

```
SELECT
    cust_xref_id, 
    MAX(txn_ts) as last_purchase_date,
    COUNT(txn_ts) as count_purchase_dates
FROM
    sales_data_table
GROUP BY
    cust_xref_id
```

Comment: Corresponding SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c19860/4/0 (you could include it in your answer).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for last purchase date and count of distinct transaction dates ( like if a person buys twice, it should be considered as one single time).
Although you mentioned you want count of dates but sample data shows you want count of distinct dates - customer 284214 transacted 9 times but distinct will give you 7.

So, here is the SQL you can use to get your result.

```
SELECT
    cust_xref_id, 
    MAX(txn_ts) as last_purchase_date,
    COUNT(distinct txn_ts) as count_purchase_dates  -- Pls note distinct will count distinct dates
FROM sales_data_table
GROUP BY  1
```